# JSON parsing error, data not displaying

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, jsonparser

I'm just starting to learn how to use JSON in Android. 
I'm supposed to make an app that display news title, section and author.

I'm not really sure if the problem is in the parsing or something else but it keeps telling me there's no data.

So can I get some help with this part if it has a problem so I can fix it or go look more to where the problem is.

the JSON code:

```
{
   "response": {
        "status": "ok",
        "userTier": "developer",
        "total": 191,
        "startIndex": 1,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "currentPage": 1,
        "pages": 20,
        "orderBy": "relevance",
        "results": [{
            "id": "film/2017/may/25/12-jours-review-raymond-depardon-documentary-psychiatric-hospital-judge",
            "type": "article",
            "sectionId": "film",
            "sectionName": "Film",
            "webPublicationDate": "2017-05-25T15:37:15Z",
            "webTitle": "12 Jours review – a devastating glimpse into broken souls",
            "webUrl": "https://www.theguardian.com/film/2017/may/25/12-jours-review-raymond-depardon-documentary-psychiatric-hospital-judge",
            "apiUrl": "https://content.guardianapis.com/film/2017/may/25/12-jours-review-raymond-depardon-documentary-psychiatric-hospital-judge",
            "fields": {
                "headline": "12 Jours review – a devastating glimpse into broken souls",
                "starRating": "4",
                "shortUrl": "https://gu.com/p/6g6hn",
                "thumbnail": "https://media.guim.co.uk/1dbf594e183ebe5428fe88c82784c55908b4753c/0_0_3598_2160/500.jpg"
            },
            "tags": [{
                "id": "profile/wendy-ide",
                "type": "contributor",
                "sectionId": "film",
                "sectionName": "Film",
                "webTitle": "Wendy Ide",
                "webUrl": "https://www.theguardian.com/profile/wendy-ide",
                "apiUrl": "https://content.guardianapis.com/profile/wendy-ide",
                "references": [],
                "firstName": "wendy",
                "lastName": "ide"
            }],
            "isHosted": false,
            "pillarId": "pillar/arts",
            "pillarName": "Arts"
        }]
    }
}
```

all I need is the `title`, `section`, `author` and the `url`.
So I wrote it like this:

```
 private static List<News> extractFeatureFromJson(String newsJSON) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newsJSON)) {
        return null;
    }
    List<News> news = new ArrayList<>();
    try {


      JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(newsJSON);
        String response = baseJsonResponse.getString("response");
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);;
        JSONArray newsArray=object.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < newsArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject currentNews = newsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject results = currentNews.getJSONObject("results");
            String title = results.getString("webTitle");
            String section = results.getString("sectionName");
            String author = results.getString("firstName");
            String url = results.getString("webUrl");

            News nNews = new News(title, section, author, url);

            news.add(nNews);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the news JSON results", e);
    }
    return news;
}
```

It's a new concept for me and I'm very confused, I'd really appreciate some help.

Edit:

I'm using a loader in the same app, if the list is empty it would display a string that there's no data and that's what it keeps on appearing. 
I have no idea what's the problem.

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<News>> loader, List<News> news) {
    View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
    loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    emptyTextView.setText(R.string.no_news);
    newsAdapter.clear();
    if (news != null && !news.isEmpty()) {
        newsAdapter.addAll(news);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share clearly the Json and what is your error?

Comment: your response is invalid please add exact response

Comment: I want to display some information from the result array in a textview, i got the json from here http://open-platform.theguardian.com/documentation/search

Comment: Use this
JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(newsJSON);
String response = baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");

Comment: which one you are using can you post exact API link which you are using

Comment: https://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=12%20years%20a%20slave&format=json&tag=film/film,tone/reviews&from-date=2010-01-01&show-tags=contributor&show-fields=starRating,headline,thumbnail,short-url&order-by=relevance&api-key=test

Comment: Your provided json in not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code for extractFeatureFromJson

```
private static List<News> extractFeatureFromJson(String newsJSON) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newsJSON)) {
        return null;
    }
    List<News> news = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(newsJSON);
        String response = baseJsonResponse.getString("response");
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);;
        JSONArray newsArray=object.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i = 0; i < newsArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject currentNews = newsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String title = currentNews.getString("webTitle");
            String section = currentNews.getString("sectionName");
            JSONArray tag = currentNews.getJSONArray("tags");
            String firstName;
            if(tag.length() != 0){
                firstName = tag.getJSONObject(0).getString("firstName");
            }
            String url = currentNews.getString("webUrl");

            News nNews = new News(title, section, author, url);

            news.add(nNews);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the news JSON results", e);
    }
    return news;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this  line

```
String response = baseJsonResponse.getString("response");
```

And Change this line

```
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
```

To

```
    JSONObject object = baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");
```

Comment: i have already tried that but still the data isn't showing

Comment: post your full Json response please

Comment: https://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=12%20years%20a%20slave&format=json&tag=film/film,tone/reviews&from-date=2010-01-01&show-tags=contributor&show-fields=starRating,headline,thumbnail,short-url&order-by=relevance&api-key=test

Comment: post your logcat error

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(newsJSON);
     JSONObject resJson =baseJsonResponse.getJSONObject("response");
     String status = resJson.getString("status");
JSONArray newsArray=resJson .getJSONArray("results");
```

Comment: doesn't work :( maybe the problem is not in the parsing

Comment: please check your responce is proper json format or not

Comment: use above code definitely its working...

Answer (score 0):

Replace this loop in ur code, everything else seems to be fine.

```
   private static List<News> extractFeatureFromJson(String newsJSON) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newsJSON)) {
            return null;
        }
        List<News> news = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(newsJSON);
            String response = baseJsonResponse.getString("response");
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);;
            String status = object.getString("status");
            if(status.equals("ok")){
            JSONArray newsArray=object.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < newsArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentNews = newsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject results = currentNews.getJSONObject("results");
                String title = results.getString("webTitle");
                String section = results.getString("sectionName");
                String author = results.getString("firstName");
                String url = results.getString("webUrl");

                News nNews = new News(title, section, author, url);

                news.add(nNews);
            }
            }else{
                //Invalid response Toast here
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the news JSON results", e);
        }
        return news;
    }
```

Comment: no luck :( it's still not showing anything

Comment: can u tell me error from logcat?

Comment: this works! in the end i was stupid and i used the wrong url. it took me a week to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

your Json type is wrong! Brackets do not match

Comment: i didn't type it myself, i got it from here https://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=12%20years%20a%20slave&format=json&tag=film/film,tone/reviews&from-date=2010-01-01&show-tags=contributor&show-fields=starRating,headline,thumbnail,short-url&order-by=relevance&api-key=test

Comment: wait 10 minute ! I will send you a code for parse this json

Comment: please see last post 
With that code you can parse Json
The information I received was just a few items
Get all items in response object and etc.. and get inside your model or list

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `JSONObject results = currentNews.getJSONObject("results");` because you alreade got the result array as `JSONArray newsArray=object.getJSONArray("results");`
 try this

```
                for (int i = 0; i < newsArray.length(); i++) {            
                JSONObject results = newsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String title = results.getString("webTitle");
                String section = results.getString("sectionName");
                String author = results.getString("firstName");
                String url = results.getString("webUrl");

                News nNews = new News(title, section, author, url);

                news.add(nNews);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        try
        {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("Your_json");

            // get response object
            JSONObject jsonObjectResponse = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");

            /*
                get Status string from jsonObjectResponse
                you can also get | userTier | total | startIndex and other strings in this json Object
             */
            String status = jsonObjectResponse.getString("status");

            // get result as Json array from jsonObjectResponse
            JSONArray jsonArrayResults = jsonObjectResponse.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayResults.length() ; i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObjectResult = jsonArrayResults.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = jsonObjectResult.getString("id");
                String type = jsonObjectResult.getString("type");
                String sectionId = jsonObjectResult.getString("sectionId");
                String sectionName = jsonObjectResult.getString("sectionName");
                String webPublicationDate = jsonObjectResult.getString("webPublicationDate");
                String webTitle = jsonObjectResult.getString("webTitle");
                String webUrl = jsonObjectResult.getString("webUrl");
                String apiUrl = jsonObjectResult.getString("apiUrl");
                JSONObject jsonObjectfields = new JSONObject(jsonObjectResult.getString("fields"));
                String fieldHeadLine = jsonObjectfields.getString("headline");
                String fieldStarRating = jsonObjectfields.getString("starRating");
                String fieldShortUrl = jsonObjectfields.getString("shortUrl");
                String fieldThumbnail = jsonObjectfields.getString("thumbnail");

                JSONArray jsonArrayTags = jsonObjectResult.getJSONArray("tags");
                for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayTags.length(); j++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObjectTags = jsonArrayTags.getJSONObject(j);
                    String tagID = jsonObjectTags.getString("id");
                    String tagType = jsonObjectTags.getString("type");
                    String tagSelectionID = jsonObjectTags.getString("sectionId");
                    String tagSectionName = jsonObjectTags.getString("sectionName");
                    // iam just get 4 string ! you can get all tags string with replacing
                }
                //** and get others  each jsonObject from result Array
            }



        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // when parse json error happend! check log  cat 
        }
```

this code parse [this link](https://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=12%20years%20a%20slave&format=json&tag=film/film,tone/reviews&from-date=2010-01-01&show-tags=contributor&show-fields=starRating,headline,thumbnail,short-url&order-by=relevance&api-key=test)

I took only a few items from each part to clarify the case